# Add a little space between the location input box and the warning message

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, warning-message

Go to [Edit profile and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) and enter an imaginary location in the Location text box, say, [*'Sagiri Mountain'*](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Sagiri_Mountain). You will be warned that this location isn't recognized (*'We don't recognize that location -- try again?'*). The problem (albeit a minor one) is that the warning message is right next to the text box with no spacing between them.

[image: No space between the input box and the warning]

The same message is displayed (and thus the same issue occurs) when the system is making a *suggestion* of what you likely meant, in case you appear to have misspelled the place name:

[image: Did you mean "Seattle, WA, USA"?]

Perhaps a padding-left of 10px to the warning message should do the trick:

[image: with padding]

I would also suggest that:

- The question mark be eliminated, as this is a suggestion, not a question
- The double-hyphen construct be replaced with a proper em-dash (—)
- The warning text be set apart from the normal field labels with some colored or otherwise distinguished text.

Comment: Shouldn't that warning message also be... somehow colored or accented to indicate that it is a warning? From the screenshot, it looks indistinguishable from the normal form labels.

Comment: @CodyGray That would probably hint that said location cannot be used (which is not true). I'm not sure why the message is even there. The results (or lack thereof) in the autocomplete dropdown _is_ already a clear indication that their input is not recognized.

Comment: @41686d6564 well, isn't it a definition of warning? Something that's *allowed*, but discouraged. If it was disallowed, it should've been an error message. That said, yeah, not sure why the message is even there since it does not matter in the end. What bothers me more is the double dash instead of an em dash :)

Comment: What bothers me is the question mark.

Comment: @khelwood - and an apostrophe, those pesky contractions, ain't they just awful? :) Wait...

Comment: @41686d6564 If you input [something similar to a real place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8YVJ.png), it'll *guess* what you meant instead - "Did you mean [placename]?" So I'm guessing the version in this question is there to indicate it's so different from anything in their system that there's no suggestion for similar places.

Comment: [This shows what I would expect the warning message to look like in the Stacks styles](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/textarea/#warning). What @Catija shows isn't a warning, but more like a suggestion. Apparently, there's no specific style for that. I would have expected blue text with an "info" icon. It would also be reasonable, in my mind, to display a [notice](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#inline) underneath the textbox field, either as a yellow warning or a blue notice. And, yes, ditch the question mark—it's a suggestion, not a question.

Comment: Nah, flex layout with spacing in between. Browsers have solutions nowadays so you don't have to do manual padding everywhere.